# Why is my class factory not populating my dynamic object's `__dict__` attribute

Tags: python

I have a class factory which dynamically builds new types (not objects/instances). The code is currently working per-se, but I can't figure out where the attributes I give it are stored. Below is an image of my driver code and output:

[image: Driver code for dynamic class creation]

All attributes and methods are set and working as expected, but they're not registered in the `__dict__` property. This is not ok, since a downstream use case will search `__dict__` for those custom types. The entire "working" factory is here:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Any

from types_extensions import void


class DynamicClassFactory:

    def __init__(self, default_base_classes: Iterable[type] = None, prefix: str = '', suffix: str = '',
                 attributes: dict[str, Any] = None) -> void:
        self.prefix: str = prefix
        self.suffix: str = suffix
        self.mixins: list[type] = [x for x in default_base_classes or (object,)]
        self.attributes: dict[str, Any] = attributes or {}

    def build(self, class_name: str, extra_mixins: Iterable[type] = (),
              attributes: dict[str, Any] = None) -> type:

        return type(
            self.prefix + class_name + self.suffix,
            self._create_bases(extra_base_classes=extra_mixins),
            {**self.attributes, **(attributes or {})}
        )

    def _create_bases(self, extra_base_classes: Iterable[type]) -> tuple[type]:
        return tuple(self.mixins + [x for x in extra_base_classes])
```

I have looked online and mainly used this as a guide: https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/ (for this particular use case of type(), Ctrl+F in the page and search "You can also call type() with three arguments" without the quotes.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I know I don't have correct error handling for illegal characters in names, it's planned.

Comment: No images of code please.

Comment: You're showing some code, but it's not a [MRE]. Please show a sample run with expected vs actual results, including any error tracebacks

Comment: Why do you expect the class attributes to be on the instance's `__dict__`? You will find them on `new_class2.__dict__` unless you set them on the instance someplace like `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass attributes to the `type` class, you're actually passing class attributes instead of instance attributes. [From documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> The *dict* dictionary contains attribute and method definitions for the **class body**; it may be copied or wrapped before becoming the `__dict__` attribute. The following two statements create identical `type` objects:
>
> ```py
> class X:
>    a = 1
>
> X = type('X', (), dict(a=1))
> ```

So the following holds true:

```
my_class2 = factory.build(...)
print(my_class2.__dict__)    # Outputs {..., x: 1, y: 2}

obj2 = my_class2()
print(obj2.__dict__)         # Outputs {}
```

You may ask how can you access `obj2.y` successfully. That's because when Python does not find a attribute in the instance (in this case, `obj2`), it'll look up in the class attributes (in this case, `my_class2`). Since there is one, it'll evaluate to it.

Comment: Correct, I posted my self-answer at the same time. I will accept yours as it's a much better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Since I'm setting class properties, I need to access it via `obj2.__class__.__dict__` instead of `obj2.__dict__`